# Unable to record video with watermark over it using Android Java CameraX API

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am unable to record video with watermark over it using CameraX API

I recorded the video using CameraX API Java.But when I place text on PreviewView it is showing over there but it is not recording.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lselc.png)

```
private void startCameraX(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

    cameraProvider.unbindAll();

    // Camera Selector
    cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
            .build();

    //Preview
    preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(pv_preview.getSurfaceProvider());




    //Image Caputer
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .build();

    //Video Capture
    videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
            .setVideoFrameRate(30)
            .setBitRate(1000000)
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(640, 480))
            .build();

    ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build();



    Camera camera = (Camera) cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            this,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            imageCapture,
            videoCapture

    );

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to edit the video stream is using Effects API and OpenGL. You need to create a [SurfaceProcessor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/SurfaceProcessor) and a [CameraEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraEffect) that targets both [PREVIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraEffect#PREVIEW()) and [VIDEO_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraEffect#VIDEO_CAPTURE()). The effect can be inserted into CameraX with the [UseCaseGroup.addEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/UseCaseGroup.Builder#addEffect(androidx.camera.core.CameraEffect)) API. Then you can use OpenGL to process the input stream and draw a watermark on it.

For a complete example, you can checkout the ToneMappingSurfaceProcessor in CameraX test app: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/ToneMappingSurfaceProcessor.kt

Comment: Can you please share the exact code which you implemented to add the watermark?

Comment: You can find the source code under: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/camera/camera-effects/src/main/java/androidx/camera/effects